# Get Google Form AND Spreadsheet Data in single script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I have a Google Form linked to a Spreadsheet. I then created a script that allows me to grab that information using a Form Submit trigger, put that information into a template document and send via email.

However, there is a column in the spreadsheet called "Invoice no." that isn't linked to the Google Form (e.g. the information in this column isn't coming from the Google Form), and it populates a sequential invoice number for each Google Form submission.

I want to be able to use this Invoice no. column, but in the script when I make the column a var, it populates in my doc template as undefined. How do I solve this problem? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I've tried flushing, but that isn't applicable because there is no "activespreadsheet", I've tried utility.sleep because I thought the information coming from google forms on form submit was too fast, but that didn't work.

I expected that when I placed an additional var under the array beneath the function that it would automatically read it like any other, so after I generated the new column it would go to that var in the array and copy over to the body. of the document.

```
function GetFormFunction(e) {  
var timestamp = e.values[0];
var Email = e.values[1];
var EmployID = e.values[2];
var EmployName = e.values[3];

//Below variable is not a part of Google Form, but generated separately on spreadsheet and necessary for template doc. The placeholder returns a code "undefined"

var InvNum = e.values[4];
```

I managed to finally solve this with @Cooper pointing me in the right direction with the below script:

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var row =  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getLastRow();
sheet.getRange(row,18).setValue(row);
var InvNum = sheet.getRange(row,18).getValue();
```

Comment: I doubt that the trigger is reading data from the linked spreadsheet.  I'd guess that it's getting it  from the Form.

Comment: Thanks for following up @Cooper. Any idea how I'd be able to get the spreadsheet data that isn't linked to the form into the document to send off in the email?

Comment: The trigger gives you a range that tells you what area of the linked spreadsheet was edited.  You should be able to get the row from that.  https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#form-submit_4

Comment: @Cooper, thanks. Getting the row isn't really the issue, the issue is that the column I added to the spreadsheet isn't a part of the form submit trigger range. So I'm more or less stumped trying to figure out how to pull the invoice no column into the script where I can use it as a variable for the doc.

Comment: But if you know the row and you know the column then `sheet.getRange(row,column).getValue()` should give you what you need? Yes? No?

Comment: @Cooper, thank you soo much for pointing me in the right direction with this. After 2 days of trying I finally got it to work with the code above (I made an edit to the post to show the script I'm using). Thanks again!